# groovy what's wrong with this basic closure?

Tags: groovy

I've got the following groovy code:

```
dataFile.filterLine() {it =~ /(${searchStr1}|${searchStr2})/ }.each { it ->
    println it
    it.split { list ->
        println "split line:  ${list[0]},  ...."
    }
}
```

The first println works great -- lists all the matching lines.   Then, the split causes an error, in fact on the second println.  Obviously it doesn't like the ${list[0]}.  But, I'm not clear what is wrong with that.

Error is:

```
No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods$4.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), wait(), grep(), getClass(), wait(long). Stacktrace follows:
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the type of what you're splitting?

Comment: Not sure what ".each" will produce, a list?   I added a println "class is: ${it.getClass()}" right above the first println, and it produced:  class is: class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods$4

Comment: ... I'm not stuck on doing a closure here, BTW.  I just want to not split apart the lines that I want out of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filterLine` doesn't return what you think it does; it's a `Writable`, containing all the matches from the input file.

Here's a minimal example:

```
f = new File("/home/dave/.bashrc")
w = f.filterLine({ it =~ /alias/ })
println w.class

s = w.toString()
println s

s.eachLine { println "==> ${it}" }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Dave, you're right (this works).  There must be a more elegant way in Groovy to filter out a line in a file, and split it into parts ...  thoughts?  Should I post a second question?

Comment: Thanks for your help Dave, I also posted a general question.

Answer (score 1):

`String.split()` doesn't take a closure argument.  I think you might want `it.split().each { list ->` for the third line.

EDIT: It's actually matching [`Collection.split(Closure)`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#split%28groovy.lang.Closure%29), where the closure is used to group the contents.

Comment: Thanks (missing closure argument makes sense, and adding .each is interesting!).  I'm taking it you mean "it.split().each { line ->", i.e. with the "line" before the "->".   I tried it like this, and still got a ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException

Comment: Ataylor, please advise too if my way of trying to split apart a line that I get out of a file is "bad" programming.  Any good way will work :-)

Comment: I clarified my "println it" to "println "LINE: ${it}", and it looks like "it" is one long line, with all the matching file lines added in with carriage returns (so it fooled me).

Comment: @Ray, you're right, fixed the `line ->` line.   But assuming the `split` is supposed to split the line into words (or lines), you want the no-arg or String arg String split, not the Closure arg Collection split.

Comment: Not sure I understand @Ataylor.  I'm going to post a general question regarding this issue, as I think it would be more useful as a general question.