# groovy read file getting certain lines, then split each retrieved line into parts

Tags: groovy

I'm thinking there must be an elegant way to do this in Groovy (i.e. a common task).  Can someone please give a code snippet?  This question is related to this entry: [groovy what's wrong with this basic closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140710/groovy-whats-wrong-with-this-basic-closure).

... it looks like the File.filterLine() method using a closure is a good start, but then once you have those lines, what is the elegant way to split them apart?  E.g. say one is trying to pick out certain lines in a comma separated file (CSV), and then split those lines apart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not concerned about efficiency or loading the whole file into memory, this will work:

```
new File("myFile.csv").readLines().findAll { it =~ ~/regexp/ }*.tokenize(",")
```

Groovy doesn't seem to have a really nice way to filter lines from a stream without loading the file into memory though.  Here's one way to do it with a small support class:

```
new LineFilter(new File("myFile.csv").newReader(), ~/regexp/)*.tokenize(",")

@groovy.transform.Canonical
class LineFilter implements Iterator {
    def source
    def filter
    def peek = []

    String next() {
        while (true) {
            if (peek) {
                return peek.pop()
            }
            def nextLine = source.readLine()
            if (nextLine == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException()
            } else if (nextLine =~ filter) {
                return nextLine
            }
        }
    }

    boolean hasNext() {
        try {
            if (!peek) {
                peek.push(next())
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false
        }
        true
    }

    void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException() }
}
```

Comment: Wow, awesome, thank you very much.  The first works, but your intuition is excellent.  I've got 150,000 line files, and it is slow.  I tried your second, but ran into a bug.  I switched "readLine" to "eachLine" (think you had a typo?),  but eachLine confuses it too ... it says  "Could not find which method eachLine to invoke from this list:, and then lists the 4 eachLine methods on java.io.File.  I'm not sure how to fix that, do you know how?

Comment: `Reader` should have a `readLine()` method.  That's why in the second example the LineFilter is called with `File(...).newReader()`.

Comment: Sorry! In my stackoverflow screen the first line in your second example was eclipsed, and I mistakenly thought the code started with the @groovy.transform.Canonical line.   I tried what you have, however even adding an import for groovy.transform.canonical, this constructor wouldn't initialize the source (got a null error).  I then tried it adding in a leading "source: ..., filter: ...", and same null error.  Please see next comment.

Comment: So then I changed it to construct the object, then set the fields.  When I run it, the filter isn't working -- it finds all the lines and dies due to too much data.  I tried initializing the filter two ways:  lineFilter.filter = ~/${my_variable_regexp}/,  and then without the leading "~".  But either way it didn't filter.  I know the ${my_variable_regexp} is good, because I use the same one in your first example.

Comment: My test case works for me with groovy 1.8.4.  The `@Canonical` is a 1.8 feature, so if you're using an earlier version, you can remove it and add the following constructor: `LineFilter(source, filter) { this.source = source; this.filter = filter }`

Comment: Thanks, I did bypass the constructor to set the properties individually.  I'm running running Groovy 1.83 in Grails 2.0, so ?  But, even setting the filter manually, it didn't work for me.  Sounds like it is fine for you, so ?

Comment: Can you provide a small example where it fails?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `splitEachLine` like this:

```
new File( 'file.csv' ).splitEachLine( /,/ ) { it ->
  println it
}
```

But without any form of example, it's hard to see what you're trying to achieve...

What's wrong with the way in that other question?

What could be better?

And seriously, if you're trying to read a CSV, then use a CSV parsing library like [GroovyCSV](http://xlson.com/groovycsv/)

Comment: Thanks Tim.  In your example, I'm looking for first filtering/selecting certain lines in the file, and then, after those are selected, splitting them.  How would one extend what you did to achieve that, say searching on lines that have "abc" in them?

Comment: @Ray Is it important that they're selected, then split, or can they be selected/split at the same time?

Comment: Thanks Dave.  Yah, selected first, and then split (i.e the first one you said).

Comment: Dave - post thought if you read this:  if the regular expression doesn't identify the line as needing to be split, then it could be merged into one.  I'm thinking this is possible using the regular expression grouping capability, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html

Comment: @Tim, thanks for your other questions -- in the other post, things kept working intermittently and we're buggy for some reason, have no idea why.  Also, it seemed like Groovy would have a more elegant solution, hence this post.